Generating random closed form expressions in Matlab compatible with str2func
Is there Matlab code that generates random closed form expressions as strings in a notation that is compatible with str2func?
Given a cell of functions and terminals and a maximal string length this is the initialization task of genetic programming but with str2func compatible strings instead of tree representation.
EDIT: I want to initialize functions with one (complex) variable 'z' and a number of constants 'a1', 'a2', ... with a depth > 4. It should be mixed functions like rational functions with exp, log and trigonometric elements.
If not directly perhaps indirectly where the string output is further transformed.
For example initialization methods in genetic programming like 'full' or 'grow' [1] generate expressions in prefix notation that can not be processed by str2func, so an additional transformation is needed.
[1] Poli, Riccardo; Langdon, William B.; McPhee, Nicholas Freitag: A Field Guide to Genetic Programming. 2008, p14
EDIT: @lvand: I tested the proposed function generateRandomExpr() with
funcSet = {@(z,a) z+a, @(z,a) z-a, @(z,a) z*a, @(z,a) z/a, @(z,a) z^a, @exp, @log, @sin, @sinh, @cos, @cosh, @tan, @tanh};

terminalSet = {'z', 'a'};

maxDepth = 5;

but got always:
Error using horzcat  
The following error occurred converting from char to function_handle:  
Too many output arguments.

Error in Test_generate_rand_expresion_for_str2func>generateRandomExpr (line 62)
            expr = [func '(' strjoin(args, ',') ')'];

Error in Test_generate_rand_expresion_for_str2func>generateRandomExpr (line 58)
                args{i} = generateRandomExpr(maxDepth - 1, funcSet, terminalSet);
``


You're going to provide more information and ideally an example of what you're trying to do.

If you have the expression tree or a prefix expression, either of those could be converted to an infix expression. It's unclear to me from your question what your inputs and desired outputs are.

@ beaker: then I would need Matlab code for prefix generation & infix converting. Strait forward infix generation would be simpler. E.g. in the GP Toolbox from J. Abonyi it is unclear how to include arbitrary functions and www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-infix-conversion/ has no Matlab version

@GünterBachelier Since you inserted a space between the @ and my name, I was not notified that you had responded. It's still unclear what your inputs and desired outputs are.

You are going to need to provide more information.
However, eyeballing what you want to generate a random closed-form expressions with str2func in MATLAB. To do this, you will need to

define a set of functions and variables to use in expressions.
build expressions recursively or iteratively

Here is an example:
function expr = generateRandomExpr(maxDepth, funcSet, terminalSet)
    % Generate random closed-form expressions recursively
    if maxDepth == 0
        % Base case: choose a terminal (variable or constant)
        expr = terminalSet{randi(numel(terminalSet))};
    else
        % Randomly choose to add a function or terminal
        if rand < 0.5 || maxDepth == 1
            expr = terminalSet{randi(numel(terminalSet))};
        else
            % Choose a function from the function set
            func = funcSet{randi(numel(funcSet))};
            numArgs = nargin(func); % Get the number of arguments for the function
            
            % Recursively generate expressions for function arguments
            args = cell(1, numArgs);
            for i = 1:numArgs
                args{i} = generateRandomExpr(maxDepth - 1, funcSet, terminalSet);
            end
            
            % Construct the expression as a string
            expr = [func '(' strjoin(args, ',') ')'];
        end
    end
end

% Example usage:

% Define your set of possible functions and terminals
funcSet = {@sin, @cos, @exp, @log, @(x, y) x + y, @(x, y) x * y}; % Operators and math functions
terminalSet = {'x', 'y', '1', '2', '3'}; % Variables and constants

% Generate random expressions of varying complexity
maxDepth = 3; % Set the maximum depth of the expression tree
randomExpr = generateRandomExpr(maxDepth, funcSet, terminalSet);

% Convert the generated string into a function handle
f = str2func(['@(x, y) ' randomExpr]);

% Display the random expression and function handle
disp(['Random Expression: ', randomExpr]);
disp(f);

This should generate an output:
Random Expression: sin(exp(x))
f = 
  function_handle with value:
    @(x,y)sin(exp(x))

Your function sets, which include functions like sin, cos, and exp, are defined as anonymous functions that are used to build the random expression.
Your terminal sets, which include constants and variables such as x, y etc are used as terminals.
Your recursive generators are the expressions that are recursively constructed. Which are either a function from the set or a terminal depending on the depth of recursion.
Your expression construction is the result of a string representing the expression which can be passed to your str2func.
If you were to reformat your question, I'll either edit or remove my post to keep the question streamlined.
